# Find English idiom

Tags: idioms

In my language, there is a idiom means:

> One person will go fast, but many people will go further.

I don't know in english, are there any idioms express this idea?  If not, how to correct above sentence with right grammar ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any close analogue, but it sounds like the purpose of this idiom is to encourage teamwork and cooperation? If so, then some English expressions with a similar purpose include:

- many hands make light work.
- two heads are better than one.
- united we stand, divided we fall.
- there's no "I" in "team".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the proverb according to which who goes:  [slow and steady wins the race](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/slow+and+steady+wins+the+race):

> - (Prov.) If you work slowly but constantly, you will succeed better than if you work fast for a short while and do not continue.
> - (Associated with Aesop's fable of "The Tortoise and the Hare.") Joy only had a little bit of time to spend sewing every day, but she worked steadily and soon had finished a beautiful quilt. Slow and steady wins the race.

(from TFD)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go quickly, go alone. If you want to go far, go together.